# SQL SELECT multiple criterias IF not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset where i want to select the records that matches my input values. But i only want to try matching a field in my dataset against the input value, if the dataset value is not NULL.

I always submit all 4 input values.
`@Tyreid`, `@CarId`,`@RegionId`,`@CarAgeGroup`

So for the first record in the dataset i get a successful output if my input values matches RegionId and CarAgeGroup.

I cant figure out how to create the SQL script for this SELECT?

My dataset

```
TyreId  CarId   RegionId    CarAgeGroup
------  -----   --------    -----------
NULL    NULL    1084            2
65      35      1084            1
5       35      1084            1
NULL    41      1085            NULL
120     NULL    NULL            NULL
NULL    NULL    1084            2
65      NULL    1084            NULL
```

Comment: Could you show us some examples of the input values and the outcomes you'd expect?

Comment: If you are comparing `value` with `NULL` you are always getting `false`. Show some input values are desire output.

Comment: If you are comparing `value` with `NULL` you are always getting `NULL`.

Comment: can any of "@Tyreid", "@CarId", "@RegionId", "@CarAgeGroup" be NULL when you pass them as parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

You might use ISNULL or Coalecse to reach the expected result, if the Field is NULL the parameter will be compared with the parameter.

```
Select * from aTable
Where ISNULL(Tyreid,@Tyreid)=@Tyreid
AND   ISNULL(CarId ,@CarId )=@CarId 
AND   ISNULL(RegionId,@RegionId)=@RegionId
AND   ISNULL(CarAgeGroup,@CarAgeGroup)=@CarAgeGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind that `NULL = <any value>` yields `NULL` you need to check for NULL column values separately:

```
WHERE (TyreId      IS NULL OR TyreId      = @Tyreid)
AND   (CarId       IS NULL OR CarId       = @CarId)
AND   (RegionId    IS NULL OR RegionId    = @RegionId)
AND   (CarAgeGroup IS NULL OR CarAgeGroup = @CarAgeGroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable 
WHERE (TyreId = @Tyreid OR TyreId IS NULL) 
    AND (CarId = @CarId OR CarId IS NULL) 
    AND (RegionId = @RegionId OR RegionId IS NULL) 
    AND (CarAgeGroup = @CarAgeGroup OR CarAgeGroup IS NULL)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ef26/3)